# Cannot output image in Laravel5.2 view

Tags: php, css, laravel, view, laravel-blade

i'm trying to output an image inside a DIV like:

```
<div style="background-image:url('{{ asset($radioProg->image)}}');
```

Even if the img seems to be uploaded correctly in my uploads folder and i can see it on my DB, i still can not see it in my view! any help?

This is my RadioController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'day' => 'required',
        'time' => 'required',
        'intro' => 'required',
        'link_streaming' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image|max:2000'
        ]);

    $radioProg = new RadioProg;
    $radioProg->name = $request->name;
    $radioProg->day = $request->day;
    $radioProg->time = $request->time;
    $radioProg->intro = $request->intro;
    $radioProg->link_streaming = $request->link_streaming;

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        if ($request->file('image')->isValid()) {

            $img_name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $temp_file = base_path() . 'uploads/radio_programs' . $img_name;
            $radioProg->image = $request->file('image')->move('uploads/radio_programs', $img_name);
        }
    }

    $radioProg->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'Tu nuevo programa de radio ha sido guardado correctamente!');

    return redirect()->route('admin.radio.index', [$radioProg->id]);
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $radioProg = RadioProg::find($id);
    return view('radio.show')->with('radioProg', $radioProg);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{   
    $radioProg = RadioProg::find($id);
    return view('radio.edit')->with('radioProg', $radioProg);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $radioProg = RadioProg::find($id);
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'day' => 'required',
        'time' => 'required',
        'intro' => 'required',
        'link_streaming' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image|max:2000'
        ]);

    $radioProg->name = $request->input('name');
    $radioProg->day = $request->input('day');
    $radioProg->time = $request->input('time');
    $radioProg->intro = $request->input('intro');
    $radioProg->link_streaming = $request->input('link_streaming');

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        if ($request->file('image')->isValid()) {

            $img_name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $temp_file = base_path() . 'uploads/radio_programs' . $img_name;
            $radioProg->image = $request->file('image')->move('uploads/radio_programs', $img_name);

        }
    }


    $radioProg->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'Tu programa de radio ha sido modificado con éxito!');

    return redirect()->route('admin.radio.index', [$radioProg->id]);

}
```

And this is my view:

```
<div class="row radio-programs">
    @foreach($radioProgs as $radioProg)
    <div class="col-md-4 {{ count($radioProgs) === 1 ? "col-md-offset-4" :""}} col-program">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-program" style="background-image:url('{{ asset($radioProg->image)}}'); background-position: center; background-size: cover;-webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-inOverlay">
                        <h3 class="text-center"><span>{{$radioProg->name}}</span></h3>
                        <h4><span>Día: todos los {{$radioProg->day}} </span></h4>
                        <h4><span>Hora: {{$radioProg->time}} </span></h4>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row button-program">
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-button-program">
                                <a href="{{url('radioProgram')}}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Entrar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

in Chrome i actually see the correct path!

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-program" style="background-image:url('http://localhost:8000/uploads/radio_programs\administrador_consorcio_300115.png'); background-position: center; background-size: cover;-webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;">
```

Comment: why do you have a "\" between "radio_programs" and "administrador_consorcio_300115.png"

Comment: radio_programs is a subfolder inside uploads folder...is actually where images are

Comment: It's not supposed to be a "/" instead?

Comment: the browser fix it automatically...it takes care of it ;-) The problem seems to be the fact that i'm using a css property inside a <div>, and not an <img src=""> tag

Comment: Please try to remove the the apostrophes ' inside of your `url:()` ... `<div class="panel panel-default panel-program" style="background-image:url(http://localhost:8000/uploads/radio_programs\administrador_consorcio_300115.png); background-position: center; background-size: cover;-webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;">`

Comment: Nope, not working :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so much to answer your question, but more to debug...

You said:

> in Chrome i actually see the correct path!

Have you tried inspecting the element in chrome that uses the `background-image` style rule and seeing what image it returns? You can even open up the image in a new tab. See image:

[image]

I think it's likely the path is incorrect if you still can't see it.

Comment: i did it and yes i can see it if i link it in a new tab!! very strange, dont know what to do

Comment: I'm guessing it's a style css issue. Try debugging the style properties using the web dev tools. Take a look at the computed background property. What do you see?

Comment: what do u mean with 'computed' Bg Pr??

Comment: Look at the second tab in the image in the answer

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the rules yet? Try removing all and applying one by one. Also try playing around with background-size:cover what happens if you remove this rule?

Answer (score 0):

Change like this may work:
**add (../)** before (**{{**)

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-program" style="background-image:url('../{{ asset($radioProg->image)}}'); background-position: center; background-size: cover;-webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;">
```